# The comparator argument of sort_by

Tags: rust

```
let mut intervals = vec![vec![1,8], vec![2,4]];
intervals.sort_by(|a, b| a[1].cmp(&b[1]));
```

- This works but I am not sure how this matches to the following function definition `F` on the book.

```
pub fn sort_by<F>(&mut self, compare: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&T, &T) -> Ordering,
```

- When a rust program is compiled, does `<instance>.<method>(<argument>)` become `<method>(&<instance>,<argument>)` ?

Comment: Mostly. The exact rules depend on the declaration of method and whether instance is a trait object.

Comment: `a` and `b` are reference in your code.

Comment: You are passing a closure, which implements `FnMut`. In this case it is not the method call itself get passed as an argument, but the ad-hoc (anonymous) closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "closure" type in Rust. Instead, for each closure, the compiler creates a type which stores the captured values. The type of a closure is then assigned implementations of the Fn traits, depending on characteristics of the closure:

- all closures are `FnOnce`
- closures which don't consume any captured values and which may (or may not) mutate captured values are `FnMut`
- closures which don't consume or mutate any captured values are `Fn`

All closures which are `Fn` are `FnMut` and all closures which are `FnMut` are `FnOnce`.

To support all suitable closures, the `sort_by` method is generic over a type `F` which is bounded by the `FnMut` trait. This allows the generic implementation of `sort_by` to call the supplied function repeatedly (the more general trait `FnOnce` wouldn't be sufficient in this regard).

Calling `sort_by` with a closure invokes `sort_by::< _type_of_the_closure_ >` but the type argument is inferred here and can't even be given explicitly as closure types are unspellable.

In this particular use case, where the comparison of `std::cmp::Ord` values, extracted from the values being sorted, is returned, `sort_by_key` would be more suitable.

```rs
let mut intervals = vec![vec![1,8], vec![2,4]];
intervals.sort_by_key(|a| a[1]);
```

As for your other question, `instance.method(argument)` is generally equivalent to `[Type/Trait]::method([&instance/&mut instance/instance], argument)`. Methods are just functions which are namespaced under a type with their first parameter being of this type. A subtle difference is that `instance.method(argument)` automatically dereferences and/or takes references of `instance` while `[Type/Trait]::method` requires that the first argument be of the exact type.